# How to use GStreamer to write/push the OpenCV processed frames over RTMP media server

Tags: c++, opencv, nginx, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am using OpenCV which I can successfully read the IP camera video stream by using the GStreamer.

```
VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();
cap.open("rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin12345@192.168.1.64:554/h264/ch33/main/av_stream" latency=0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink");
Mat frame = new Mat();
while(cap.read(frame)) {
        // do something with mat
        .....
        // and now write the mat to RTMP stream (network)
}
```

I have opened the writer as below:

```
VideoWiter writer = new VideoWriter();
boolen open = writer.open("gst-launch-1.0 -v appsrc ! ffenc_flv ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://192.168.1.65/mylive/stream live=1");
if(!open) {
    System.out.println("error open writer");
    return;
}
```

`rtmp://192.168.1.65/mylive/stream` is the NGINX media server address.
So I want to send the images to this server or directly to the HTML page.

Comment: Remove `"gst-launch-1.0 -v ` from the string and add parameter `cv::CAP_GSTREAMER`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried a lot of commands (with and without gst-launch-1.0 -v) and (with and without CAP_GSTREAMER), but there is no output when receiving the data on the other side (video tag of HTML or VLC player). So can you tell me, is it possible to out an RSTP or RTMP stream via GStreamer? Can you give a working example? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried your Gstreamer pipeline in terminal? You should have a working pipeline before using OpenCV Gstreamer API.